# Do-while statements beginner java max-min prompt

Tags: java, while-loop, do-while, statements

Hey guys I new to Java and on do-while statements, the question asks me to create a prompt that asks for a max and a min value, then it asks for another value between my max and min values. "The user should be continually be prompted until a number within the range is entered. Im having a hard time wrapping my head around using a do-while statement so some help would be nice thanks! Also try to keep it simple!

```
package Chapter6Java;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Chapter6Prompter {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        int max, min, between;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a min value: ");
        min = input.nextInt(); 

        System.out.print("Enter a max value: ");
        max = input.nextInt();

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a value between your min and max values:");
            between = input.nextInt();
        } while (between != max && between != min);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your condition in the while as:

```
while (between >= max || between <= min);
```

Since you are checking that between is in range you should check if its greater than or equal to minimum value and less than or equal to maximum value.

Comment: `between <= min || between >= max` instead? `<` and `>` if inclusive.

Comment: I changed it and its still messed up, when entering a number now in-between the values, the program terminates, and when entering values within the max and min values, it keeps asking me for a value.

Comment: @Dukeling, yes, you are right, I misread the question thinking that it should keep going if the number is in range.

Comment: ah there we go, works like a charm thank you guys for all your help! So if im reading that statement correct, if the value entered when asked for the between value is <= min or >=max it will keep asking?

Answer (score 4):

You want to repeat the loop if the number rentered in not in range

so condition will be - `while (between > max || between < min);`

Comment: nvm, if i choose a max of like 9, and min of 5, and give it 6, still ask me for another value, and its not terminating.

Comment: Are you sure you entered Min first and Max second ?